# Page Always Redirects to Home

Tags: routing

This is a basic general question, but my site always redirects to the home landing page even when I click the links it redirects.  So thissite.com/link1 shows in the URL input, but the home page still shows.

Answer (score 0):

? You probably have a segment related issue; EE is probably expecting a {segment_1} to look up channel entries from, and just defaults to something else. You might want to set your templates to require all segments. Can you post your template code and some more details? Are you using Structure or the Pages module??